# Python requests is not extracting all elements

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract TR data from the following page:
http://www.datasheetcatalog.com/catalog/p1342320.shtml

I am using requests and `BeautifulSoup`. However, I don't get all rows ( only 12 instead of 22 from second table). Does anybody have an explanation for this (provided that the rows are there when printing response.content.)?

Here is the code I am using :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

session = requests.Session()

url = 'http://www.datasheetcatalog.com/catalog/p1342320.shtml'
response = session.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"lxml")

trs=  soup.findAll('table')[8].findAll('tr')
print (len(trs))
```

Comment: I got `22` as output of `print(len(tr2))`... What is your desired output?

Comment: weird ! ...I get 12 not 22

Comment: @Andersson which python version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6

Comment: @Andersson did you try several times and you always get 22 ?

Comment: Yep, still getting `22`

Comment: OMG !! I hoe that someoneelse can help with this !

Comment: Can you just save `response.content` into file.html and open it in browser to check what exactly you're trying to parse/

Comment: I did ...and all rows are there !!!  i hope someone else can try ...i tested it on my personal machine and on cloud and both give '12'

Comment: Which data from rows exactly you're looking for? Links?

Comment: yes links and parts names

Comment: Maybe try with another selector... `trs =  soup.select('a[title^="View"]')` `for tr in trs: print(tr['href'], tr.text)`

Comment: @Andersson same result with your code : missing the last 10 rows!!

Comment: Thanks @Andersson.. I fixed it, please refer to my answer below . How can i recommend your profile here , i am still new to stackoverflow !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After detailed examination of the html page i found that beautifulsoup stopped after hitting comments (). So the solution is to change the parser from "lxml" to "html5lib" :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html5lib")
```

Comment: @ewwink Thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

the html is not valid which broke `BeautifulSoup` here to fix

```
....
html_doc = response.text.replace('<table <', '<')
html_doc = re.sub(r'<\!--\s+\d+\s+--\!>', '', html_doc)
html_doc = re.sub(r'</?font.*?>' ,'', html_doc)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

trs=  soup.findAll('table')[8].findAll('tr')
print (len(trs))
```

note: using `lxml` return 7 not 22

Comment: just changing the parser from lxml to html5lib works! thanks